# form.serialize() sends empty object - Django forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, forms

My **AJAX query sends an empty object** `Object {  }` on button click - it should be sending form data.

I have a form with checkboxes. It renders and functions, and the HTML is like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" data-id="filter-form">

//This is from Django's CSRF token
<form  method="post" >
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value=.../>

<div class="form-group"> <div id="div_id_vacant" class="checkbox"> 
  <label for="id_vacant" class="">Is Vacant</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vacant" class="checkboxinput" id="id_vacant" />
</div></div>

...more of the same inputs...

</form>
</form>

<hr/>

<button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-info" data-filter-leads-url="/leads/ajax/filter">Search</button>
<button id="download-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-filter-leads-url="/leads/csv">Download</button>
```

I also have some JQuery stuff. It is **supposed** to read the form and send an AJAX request via post to a Django view. It looks like this:

```
{Django CSRF code here}

var searchBtn = $("#search-btn");
searchBtn.click(function () {
    var form = $("#filter-form");

    $.ajax({
        url: searchBtn.attr("data-filter-leads-url"),
        method: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("There was an error.");
            console.log(data.error())
        }
    });

});
```

I've also tried:

```
var formData = new FormData(form[0]);
```

It sends an empty object as well.

**Empty object confirmed through** Django view printing `request.POST` and a `console.log(form.serlialize())` command as well as a `console.log(formData)`  command. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: You can't nest `<form>` elements.

Comment: :-) Django is doing this magic... it is working though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is using data-id, add id in it and try again.

```
<form method="post" action="" data-id="filter-form" id='filter-form'>
```

Hopefully it helps.

Best Regards,

Hatjhie

Comment: Coding while tired is not recommended. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="" data-id="filter-form" id="filter-form">
//This is from Django's CSRF token
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value=.../>

<div class="form-group"> <div id="div_id_vacant" class="checkbox"> 
  <label for="id_vacant" class="">Is Vacant</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vacant" class="checkboxinput" id="id_vacant" />
</div></div>

...more of the same inputs...

</form>

<hr/>

<button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-info" data-filter-leads-url="/leads/ajax/filter">Search</button>
<button id="download-btn" class="btn btn-default" data-filter-leads-url="/leads/csv">Download</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
{Django CSRF code here}

var searchBtn = $("#search-btn");
searchBtn.click(function () {
    var form = $("#filter-form");
    $.ajax({
        url: searchBtn.attr("data-filter-leads-url"),
        method: "POST",
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("There was an error.");
            console.log(data.error())
        }
    });

});
```